# Can I share the crosshair with two graph in pyqtgraph (pyqt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am implemented two graphs in pyqt5 with pyqtgraph, and want to share cursor between two graphs.

I have a program result at the following:
[image]

And I want to share the crosshair like:
[image]

Can pyqtgraph do it ? Many thanks.

Following is my code (update), it will show 2 graph and the cursor will only allow move in graph2 only. However, I want the cursor can move and get data from graph1 and graph2.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import MultiPlotWidget


class GUI_create_main_window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.plot1 = pg.PlotWidget()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plot1)

        self. plot2 = pg.PlotWidget()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.plot2)

        self.draw_cursor()

        self.setLayout(main_layout) 
        self.show()

    #hair cross event    
    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        try:
            if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and
                source is self.plot2.viewport()):
                pos = event.pos()
                if self.plot2.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
                    mousePoint = self.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
                    self.vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
                    self.hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())

            return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            err = sys.exc_info()[1]
            print(str(err))

    def draw_cursor(self):
        #cross hair
        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False, pen=pg.mkPen('k', width=1))
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False, pen=pg.mkPen('k', width=1), label='{value:0.1f}',
                                        labelOpts={'position':0.98, 'color': (200,0,0), 'movable': True, 'fill': (0, 0, 200, 100)})
        self.plot2.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.plot2.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.vb = self.plot2.plotItem.vb

        #set mouse event
        self.plot2.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.plot2.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = GUI_create_main_window()
    currentExitCode = app.exec_()
```

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I update a example code for it. However, the cursor only allow move in graph2, but I want to move and get data in both graph1 and graph2.

Comment: If you want the cross hair to be shown on both sides at the same time, that is not possible, so there are 2 possibilities: the first one is that the cross hair moves from one plot to another **or** create 2 cross hair that are synchronized. which one do you want?

Comment: see this: https://imgur.com/a/DBz09ia

Comment: @eyllanesc can you explain more the cross hair moves from one plot to another?

Comment: Forget that, I was confused with your requirement, your option is to have a crosshair for each plot. Why do you want to share the crosshair ?, I see it forced.

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to get the data from both graph and have the clear sight on graph. if many curves in the same graph, it will be dazzled.

Comment: and why do not you use 2 crosshairs? one for each plot.

Comment: @eyllanesc this is also a way to solve my problem

Comment: Do you want both haircross to have the same position with respect to each plot? I mean they are synchronized or not.

Comment: @eyllanesc I will try to synchronized cursor in 2 plot. Can you explain more the cross hair moves from one plot to another, which you said before.

Comment: you have to set each crosshair to the other plot when the cursor enters the other plot perhaps using the enterEvent. But the crosshair will only be on a plot at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is kind of late but after struggling with similar problem I came up with a solution.

First of all we can capture mouse movements on pyqtgraph plots by installing 'SignalProxy' on their scene.

For example:

```
self.proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.p.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=120, slot=self.mouseMoved)
```

This will call mouseMoved method on when mouse move signal is emitted.

We can get mouse position converted to scene position with

```
def mouseMoved(self, evt):
    pos = evt[0]
    mousePoint = self.p.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
    x, y = int(mousePoint.x()), int(mousePoint.y())
```

now we can set vLine pos to x and hLine pos to y on if we can have access to other graph's plot we can also set their vLine pos to x (since x axis should match)

we can link their x axis together (same movement on x axis is applied on other graph) by:

```
plot.setXLink(other_plot)
```

**Side notes**:

- I set up two graphs by subclassing pyqtgraph's GraphicsLayoutWidget and adding plots to them individually I'm sure there should be a way of doing it in a single subclass but doing something like...

  ```
   self.addPlot(title="Plot 1")
   self.addPlot(title="Plot 2")
  ```

  ...creates two plots next to each other rather than stacked on top of
  each other - we want to only link vLines anyways.
- we can access other graph by something like this:

  ```
   self.top_graph = TopGraph()
   self.bottom_graph = BottomGraph()

   self.top_graph.other_graph = self.bottom_graph # set bottom graph in top graph to access it in bottom graph
   self.bottom_graph.other_graph = self.top_graph # set top graph in bottom graph to access it in top graph
  ```

maybe we can do global variables as well but I'm not sure that it is a good practice.

So it all adds up to:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        main_widget = QWidget()
        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        self.top_graph = TopGraph()
        self.bottom_graph = BottomGraph()

        self.top_graph.other_graph = self.bottom_graph # set bottom graph in top graph to access it in bottom graph
        self.bottom_graph.other_graph = self.top_graph # set top graph in bottom graph to access it in top graph

        self.top_graph.p.setXLink(self.bottom_graph.p)

        
        #example plot
        x = range(-50, 51)
        y1 = [i**2 for i in x]
        y2 = [-i**2 for i in x]

        self.top_graph.p.plot(x, y1, pen=pg.mkPen("r", width=3))
        self.bottom_graph.p.plot(x, y2, pen=pg.mkPen("g", width=3))
        

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter.addWidget(self.top_graph)
        splitter.addWidget(self.bottom_graph)

        main_layout.addWidget(splitter)
    
class TopGraph(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = self.addPlot()

        self.p.hideAxis("bottom")

        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False, pen=pg.mkPen('k', width=1))
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False, pen=pg.mkPen('k', width=1), label='{value:0.1f}',
                                        labelOpts={'position':0.98, 'color': (200,0,0), 'movable': True, 'fill': (0, 0, 200, 100)})

        self.p.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.p.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)

        self.proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.p.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=120, slot=self.mouseMoved)

    def mouseMoved(self, evt):
        pos = evt[0]
        if self.p.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            self.hLine.show() # show this graph's h line since we are now in control

            mousePoint = self.p.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            x, y = int(mousePoint.x()), int(mousePoint.y())
            self.vLine.setPos(x)
            self.hLine.setPos(y)
            self.other_graph.vLine.setPos(x)
            self.other_graph.hLine.hide() # hide other graphs h line since we don't controll it here

class BottomGraph(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = self.addPlot()

        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False, pen=pg.mkPen('k', width=1))
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False, pen=pg.mkPen('k', width=1), label='{value:0.1f}',
                                        labelOpts={'position':0.98, 'color': (200,0,0), 'movable': True, 'fill': (0, 0, 200, 100)})

        self.p.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
        self.p.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)

        self.proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.p.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=120, slot=self.mouseMoved)

    def mouseMoved(self, evt):
        pos = evt[0]
        if self.p.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
            self.hLine.show() # show this graph's h line since we are now in control
            mousePoint = self.p.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
            x, y = int(mousePoint.x()), int(mousePoint.y())
            self.vLine.setPos(x)
            self.hLine.setPos(y)
            self.other_graph.vLine.setPos(x)
            self.other_graph.hLine.hide() # hide other graphs h line since we don't controll it here

def main():
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

    app = QApplication([])    
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
    window.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```